# Excel VBA, Loop Recording Answer

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I am trying to write some code to choose start time and end times of a shift using input data for shift duration which is read from a column (reports times if cell is not empty).

I am just debugging at the moment before I try and hard code with variables and ranges however

my

```
  If Cells(i, j).Value <> "" Then
         Shiftduration = Cells(i, j).Value * (0.5 / 12)
```

lines are not working correctly and are returning 0 values when I am testing, as their values are not being recorded. Thus it not taking into account the actual start time of a shift ie (Shift end time - shift duration)

```
Sub Test2()
    Sheets("Test").Select

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim Shiftduration As Long
    Dim ShiftStart As Long

    For i = 31 To 44 
    For j = 4 To 4 
        If Cells(i, j).Value <> "" Then
            Shiftduration = Cells(i, j).Value * (0.5 / 12)
            nextshift = Cells(i + 1, 1).Value
            ShiftstartRange = nextshift - Shiftduration
            Cells(1, 21) = nextshift
            Cells(1, 22) = Shiftduration
            Cells(i, 8) = ShiftstartRange
        Else
        End If
    Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

All of my code

Thanks!

Comment: Please do us (and yourself!) and yourself a favour and indent your code properly! (as my edit shows you).  To debug, after `Shiftduration = ...` add `Debug.Print i, j, Cells(i, j).Value, Shiftduration`.  What do you see in the Immediate Window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed  `Shiftduration` and `ShiftStart` from `Long` to `Double`.
And I specify with which sheet your are working.

Let me know if its works like you want

```
     Sub Test2()
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim i As Long, j As Long
        Dim Shiftduration As Double
        Dim ShiftStart As Double

        Set wb = ThisWorkbook
        Set ws = wb.Sheets("Test")

        For i = 31 To 44
                 For j = 4 To 4
                If ws.Cells(i, j).Value <> "" Then

                    Shiftduration = ws.Cells(i, j).Value * (0.5 / 12)

                 nextshift = ws.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value

                ShiftstartRange = nextshift - Shiftduration

                ws.Cells(1, 21) = nextshift
                ws.Cells(1, 22) = Shiftduration
                ws.Cells(i, 8) = ShiftstartRange

             Else

            End If

        Next j
   Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome! Work great! Thanks